# What is the meaning of "the green and blue of the crops"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions, meaning-in-context

I'm reading the *My mother never worked* essay by Bonnie Smith-Yackel.

> In the other fields, when the oats and flax began to head out, the green and blue of the crops were hidden by the bright yellow of wild mustard.

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: I can't think of anything but the actual colors of the crops, which are green and blue.

Comment: but why green and blue? what kind of crops has the green and blue color?

Comment: Well, I really don't know as I am not familiar with crops... :( I hope someone who is better at literature will be able to answer your question!

Answer (score 9):

Many crops (including [oats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oat)) are green. [Flax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFlax_field.JPG) has blue flowers.

[Wild mustard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWild_Mustard_flower.jpg) has yellow flowers.

[Nowadays, in England, more and more fields are [a virulent yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapeseed), but that's not what you were asking about.]

Comment: That is rape and there is a huge market for its seed. It has certainly brought some colour to the Norfolk landscape ion May & June.

Comment: Can you please explain more? WS2

Comment: @Fati93: WS2 was replying to my throw-away comment. It is not really relevant to your question.

Comment: +1 And 'begin to head out' means that the seedhead is beginning to emerge from the 'boot' stage, when the head is still enclosed in the tightly-wrapped final leaf, into 'head' stage, when it stands free at the top of the stalk.